# is this proper bem naming?

Tags: css, naming, bem

Is this proper naming using bem convention ?
using collapse in element

```
 <nav class="navigation">
      <div class="navigation__collapse">
          <div class="navigation__collapse-button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
          <div class="navigation__collapse-menulist"></div>
      </div>
 </nav>
```

or not using collapse in element

```
<nav class="navigation">
      <div class="navigation__collapse">
          <div class="navigation__button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
          <div class="navigation__menulist"></div>
      </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: It depends: are you willing to use another `navigation__button` somewhere else inside your nav element? if so then maybe it's better the former syntax. Or also you could use the latter code but adding a modifier , e.g. `class="navigation__button navigation__button--collapse"`

Comment: isn't naming conventions opinion based ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're about to use the `-button` and `-menulist` elements only inside the `__collapse` element, might be a good idea to prefix them with `collapse-`, like your first example.

Another trick could be to start a new Block inside the `navigation` component, called just "collapse" like so:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="collapse">
        <div class="collapse__button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        <div class="collapse__menulist"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This could indicate that the "collapse" component might be used outside of "navigation" sometimes.

For me, it always depends on which *relationships between the Blocks I want to emphasize*.

Base on my experience, a lot of people might do it like your second example, simply because moving the elements around or wrapping them in another component under "navigation" in future could be less problematic (won't require name modifying).

PS: Here's [a good read](https://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), related to this topic.